# how to ios simulator reset/reinstall ? (xcode other version build after not good work;)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

### `Problem`

- xcode 6.4 , simulator iphone 4s - ios 8.4 is not good work (bug crash)
- exc_bad_access - other thread

### `State`

1. i used xcode 6.4 , simulator iphone 4s - ios 8.4
2. xcode 7.1.1 , simulator 9.0 use after (one time build and run , may
   be simulator update)
3. xcode 6.4 , simulator not good work

### `I try that (not solve)`

1. xcode -> windows -> devices -> delete & create
2. xcode 6.4 reinstall (delete & install) and build (edit line)
3. simulator -> Reset Content and Settings
4. xcode -> preferences derived data - delete

### `Add Try`

1. runtime simulator file delete
   /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes
2. caches file delete
   /Users/[User Name]/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode

Comment: xcode is not problem. this bug is anthor problem. but I learned how to completely remove the xcode ^^

Answer (score 1):

This can not be done.

Because its a part of SDK. So you have to reinstalled Xcode again.

Comment: not solved.. my all xcode delete (4.x ~ 7.2)..... but ....